# How do you debug edebug specs?

Tags: edebug, declare

As I write progressively more ambitious macros I find my `(declare (debug specs))` more involved. There're times where I really wish I could step debug the spec matching itself, or at least perform the match on some form given a spec. Looks like Edebug has all the required parts in place, but it is so stateful that I keep running into errors where some flag or index is set to the wrong thing, etc. I just can't figure out all the wrapping I need to do to match some form against the speclist I supply. This is as far as I've gotten:

```
(defun match-debug-spec (form specs)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert (format "%S" form))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let* (edebug-offsets
           (cursor (edebug-new-cursor
                    (list (edebug-read-storing-offsets (current-buffer)))
                    (list edebug-offsets))))
      (edebug-match cursor specs))))

(match-debug-spec
 '(funcall (lambda (a b &rest args) (list* a b args)) 1 2 3 4)
 '(&rest form))
```

This is where I get `(void-variable edebug-offset-index)` error. I tinkered a lot, but I run into something every time. Doesn't help that the implementation isn't exactly documented. I have to guess at what `cursors` are and all the magic it performs while instrumenting code. Can anyone give pointers?

Someone [spec'ed the entire `CL` package](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/system/i386_deb50/os-ubuntu-9.04/usr/athena/share/emacs/22.2/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-specs.el) and I refuse to believe they managed to convince the spec matcher just by trial and error. How do I do it systematically?

Comment: I played in that code years ago, but it's too fuzzy now, sorry.  Please send patches via `M-x report-emacs-bug` adding comments to the code (those can be either things you discovered, or questions about the code).  You might also want to discuss this (even as a monologue showing your progress and set backs) on `emacs-devel` where you may have more luck finding people knowledgeable and interested in this.